# Iterated log limit proof

Tags: calculus, limits

What the easiet way to prove limit with iterate log? For example how do you find the limit log@n/logn?when log@ is iterated log

Comment: You might keep in mind our guildelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) , in particular [how to provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) , and mathematical expressions should be [typesetted with Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164). As written your post has no context and is unreadable and so may attract close votes.